# Cannot find BitcoinSecret.cs after downloading NBitcoin via Nuget

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget, bitcoin

I am trying to use the [NBitcoin](https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin) library for the first time. I downloaded the newest version via Nuget and started a new .NET MVC4 test solution.

The first class I am using is `BitcoinSecret` :

```
var paymentSecret = new BitcoinSecret("PrivateKey");
```

I have the includes `using NBitcoin` and `using Nbitcoin.Protocol` and it seems to be referencing the class fine...until I try to run the solution and step though my usage.

When it hits this line I get a `BitcoinSecret.cs Not Found` Error.

More Information:

`Locating source for 'c:\Users\NICO\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Bitcoin.Private\NBitcoin\BitcoinSecret.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {e2 1b 4e 9f 4 9d c1 9c eb 9a bf 9d 6c 4c e4 70}
Determining whether the checksum matches for the following locations:
1: C:\Users\Cavan.Flynn\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Shared\v02\DecompilerCache\decompiler\F43E8875-2E77-484D-B4E6-9C0B4E24CEA5\1f\96f9322f\BitcoinSecret.cs Checksum: MD5 {b8 fe 82 8d df e1 26 62 a2 1f 99 8b fe 75 4 c0} Checksum doesn't match.
The file 'c:\Users\NICO\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Bitcoin.Private\NBitcoin\BitcoinSecret.cs' does not exist.`

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I haven't ever had to deal with an error like this when getting something from Nuget.

Answer (score -1):

Check the path listed in the output and see if the file exists, If it doesn't then go to [HERE](https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin/tree/master/NBitcoin) and download the BiutcoinSecret.cs file and place it there. Might be worth downloading the whole package from git and adding it manually.

Comment: Actually, after reading some posts, I think that an uncaught exception is happening in the library in binary form. The uncaught exception causes the debugger to try to find the line of code which caused it but I only have the compiled code.

Comment: Download the full source from github and build it yourself, then add the reference to the one you built. Or log a issue with the dev sounds maybe.

Answer (score -1):

> [cfly24](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4661184/cfly24): Actually, after reading some posts, I think that an uncaught exception is happening in the library in binary form. The uncaught exception causes the debugger to try to find the line of code which caused it but I only have the compiled code.

Because of this I believe this will not be a problem anymore, since Nicolas has added real-time debugging to NBitcoin via [GitLink](https://github.com/GitTools/GitLink)